# extending a core block doesn't work inside the editor

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

i want to extend the group core block, and add to it a rotate inline style. i read and use the hooks. when i add the rotate it is saved and display correctly in the front. But nothing is changed in the editor even though i have a function to update the attribute.

this is my code for the edit part to extend the core group block:

```
const testingAdvancedControls = wp.compose.createHigherOrderComponent(

(BlockEdit) => {

return (props) => {

    // prepare all the variables needed 

    //const { post_id, block_count } = this.props; 

    const { Fragment } = wp.element;

    const {
        PanelBody,
        RangeControl,
    } = wp.components;

    const { InspectorAdvancedControl, InspectorControls, ColorPalette } = wp.blockEditor;

    const { attributes, setAttributes, isSelected, post_id, block_count, clientId, context } = props;


    //functions 

    const updateRotate = (newR) => {
        setAttributes({ rotate: (newR === undefined ? '' : newR) });
    }

    return (

        <Fragment>
            <BlockEdit {...props} />
            {isSelected &&
                <InspectorControls>

                    {isSelected && (props.name == 'core/group') &&

                        <PanelBody title={__('test rotate', 'testing')}
                            initialOpen={false}>

                            <RangeControl
                                label={__('Rotate', 'testing')}
                                value={attributes.rotate}
                                onChange={updateRotate}
                                min={-50}
                                max={50}
                                step={0.1}
                                help={__('Rotate the group', 'testing')}
                                allowReset={true}
                                initialPosition={0}
                            />

                        </PanelBody>
                    }

                </InspectorControls>

            }

        </Fragment>

    )

}

  }, 'testingAdvancedControls'

  );

   wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'editor.BlockEdit',
    'gutrs/add-testing-controls',
    testingAdvancedControls
);
```

why the rotation doesn't displayed inside the editor? any idea? if i give the rotete attribute a value in the editor it is passed to the front end but nothing in the editor.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Editor renders classNames and styles differently to the frontend; with added specificity. To add your own rotate control that updates the visual style the Editor, there are 3 key steps:

1. Add a rotate attribute to `core/group` via [registerBlockType](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/block-filters/#blocks-registerblocktype):

```js
function addRotateAttribute(settings, name) {
    if (name !== 'core/group') {
        return settings;
    }

    return lodash.assign({}, settings, {
        attributes: lodash.assign({}, settings.attributes, {
            rotate: {
                type: 'number',
                default: 0
            },
        }),
    });
}

wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'blocks.registerBlockType',
    'gutrs/add-rotate-attribute',
    addRotateAttribute
);
```

2. Add the Inspector Controls to the target block (*simplified version of your code*)

```js
const { createHigherOrderComponent } = wp.compose;
const { InspectorControls } = wp.blockEditor;
const { PanelBody, RangeControl } = wp.components;

const testingAdvancedControls = createHigherOrderComponent((BlockEdit) => {

    return (props) => {
        const { attributes, setAttributes } = props;

        return (
            <>
                <BlockEdit {...props} />
                {props.name == 'core/group' && (
                    <InspectorControls>
                        <PanelBody title={__('test rotate', 'testing')}
                            initialOpen={false}>
                            <RangeControl
                                label={__('Rotate', 'testing')}
                                value={attributes.rotate}
                                onChange={(val) => setAttributes({ rotate: val })}
                                min={-50}
                                max={50}
                                step={0.1}
                                help={__('Rotate the group', 'testing')}
                                allowReset={true}
                                initialPosition={0}
                            />
                        </PanelBody>
                    </InspectorControls>
                )}
            </>
        );
    };
}, 'testingAdvancedControls');

wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'editor.BlockEdit',
    'gutrs/add-testing-controls',
    testingAdvancedControls
);
```

3. Alter the props of [BlockListBlock](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/block-filters/#editor-blocklistblock) to add an inline style for rotate using the block attributes for the Editor only:

```js
const withRotate = createHigherOrderComponent(
    (BlockListBlock) => {

        return (props) => {

            const {
                name: blockName,
                attributes: { style, rotate },
                wrapperProps,
            } = props;
          
            if (rotate === undefined) {
                // Block doesn't support rotate, return default props
                return <BlockListBlock {...props} />;
            }

            // Setup new props to add inline rotate style
            const newProps = {
                ...props,
                wrapperProps: {
                    ...wrapperProps,
                    style: {
                        rotate: rotate + 'deg',
                        ...wrapperProps?.style,
                    },
                },
            };

            return <BlockListBlock {...newProps} />;
        }
    },
    'withRotateStyle'
);

wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'editor.BlockListBlock',
    'gutrs/with-rotate-style',
    withRotate
);
```

Reference: Based on how [withChildLayoutStyles](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/f32a7def563a4937000aa604530579a9eb955e6c/packages/block-editor/src/hooks/layout.js#L442) is implemented.

**Result:**
[image: Group Block with Rotate]

It's an interesting result that could make adding more content a bit tricky, but I was curious to see how it would work out..

Comment: thank you so much!
i wasn't aware i needed another hook for that. i thought one should use three hooks:
1 - blocks.registerBlockType = add attributes.
2 - editor.BlockEdit = for the edit
3 - blocks.getSaveContent.extraProps = save props for the front end

you saved me !!! thanks

Comment: have any idea why when i try to add also scale, it doesn't work again? i just added the scale attribute, as with the rotate and it doesn't work anymore. both doesn't work. and i get no error in the console.

Comment: No worries, glad to hear you have it working. To add scale would be the same, register the scale attribute a number and use `... style: {rotate: rotate + 'deg', scale: scale + '%', ...wrapperProps?.style} ...` in withRotateStyle.